# IronPython: TopNamespaceTracker.PublishComTypes throws AccessViolationException

Tags: ironpython

I'm developing a cartography application in C# and I plan to use IronPython as a scripting extension of the application. I've been successfully using IronPython for several months and most users don't have any issues with it, but a small percentage of users is having problems.

With the help from one of them I managed to dig out the exception stack trace. The exception occurs while calling the `Python.CreateEngine()` method:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. 
---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 
Failed to load language 'IronPython 2.6.2': Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. 
---> System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
at Microsoft.Scripting.Actions.TopNamespaceTracker.PublishComTypes(Assembly interopAssembly)
at IronPython.Runtime.Binding.PythonBinder.DomainManager_AssemblyLoaded(Object sender, AssemblyLoadedEventArgs e)
at IronPython.Runtime.Binding.PythonBinder..ctor(PythonContext pythonContext, CodeContext context)
at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext..ctor(ScriptDomainManager manager, IDictionary`2 options)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.LanguageConfiguration.LoadLanguageContext(ScriptDomainManager domainManager, Boolean& alreadyLoaded)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.DlrConfiguration.LoadLanguageContext(ScriptDomainManager manager, LanguageConfiguration config)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.DlrConfiguration.TryLoadLanguage(ScriptDomainManager manager, AssemblyQualifiedTypeName providerName, LanguageContext& language)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.ScriptDomainManager.GetLanguageByTypeName(String providerAssemblyQualifiedTypeName)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptRuntime.GetEngineByTypeName(String assemblyQualifiedTypeName)
at IronPython.Hosting.Python.GetEngine(ScriptRuntime runtime)
```

I couldn't find anything on Google that would be related to this.
Some info about the user's environment:

- Win7 64bit
- Using .NET 2.0-3.5 (not 4.0)
- IronPython is not installed in GAC, the app uses assemblies locally on the disk (v 2.6.2)
- The user runs the application as an ordinary user (not administrator)

I use Win7 64bit myself, but I didn't have any such problems.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is occurring somewhere in IronPython's COM interop code, but I'm not exactly sure why - the code where the exception occurred pulls COM types out of interop assemblies. You'll have to (somehow) figure out what assembly is getting loaded in the AppDomain when the exception happens, which will probably require live debugging or a custom IronPython build.

I'm not sure if it's a bug in IronPython, or if there's a squirrelly COM object on the user's machine that causes IronPython to break, but my guess is the latter.